# watching promise with $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, watch

I build a directive that have attribute that point on promise. and when promise resolved i want to running a function that do something with the data. like that :

```
 scope.$watch('source', function (dataSource) {
               if( !dataSource ) return ;
               dataSource.then(function ( d ) {
                   dataToView( d );
               });
           });
```

but there a problem . `source` can change multiple times in a very short time and every time I register a handler to current promise.
so for example if `source` changed 3 times `dataToView()` called 3 times! for promises that not any more relevant .

what I realy want is to call `dataToView()` just when the promise binding to `source` resolved .

anyone have idea how to solved that ?

Comment: Have you considered using <div ng-if="!source.$resolved"> and <div ng-if="source.$resolved"> ?

Comment: Seems you're trying to use $watch in an unintended way. Why not just make a function called `setSource` that does this?

Comment: concept shown doesn't make a lot of sense. Show all code relevant to this promise

Comment: the `source` changed from outside by the user that make changes in some filters . and I need Promise and not actual Data because I show loding animation while the time the user waiting for the Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need somekind of cancelable callback,
you can do this that way:

```
 scope.$watch('source', function (dataSource) {
    if( !dataSource ) return ;
    var currentCallbackId = Date.now();
    dataSource.then(function (myId, d ) {
        if (myId !== currentCallbackId) {
            return;
        }

       dataToView( d );
    }.bind(null, currentCallbackId));
});
```

Explanation:
You generate to each callback unique id, that the callback aware to when it invoked. (using bind that passes it as the first param to the callback)

You save the latest callback id in a closure var (can be also on the 'this') and when the callback invoked, it checks if its still relevant

Comment: I don't get it, how are you supposed to get `myID` from the `then` callback? `then` callbacks take only parameter.

Comment: doesn't make sense to watch a promise in the first place

Comment: @JuanMendes i'm using bind. the first param is the this, the other params sent as arguments to the callback...

Comment: @Bnaya, if you are binding it yourself, how would you expect `myId !== currentCallbackId` to be true?

Comment: **clever solution of using `bind`** .This effectively solves a variety of problems of this kind. I will try to think about it a little bit more and maybe read the angular#$parse 1.2 that handled Promise natively if I not find something more generaly for sure I take your solution

Comment: @JuanMendes, the currentCallbackId is binded by value (copied), that means that even if the closure var currentCallbackId is changing, it will retain its original value as the callback param.
 read about the bind method

Comment: [I am aware of `Function.bind`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&pagesize=50&q=user%3a227299%20bind), I'm saying that this function never changes `currentCallbackId`. Every time it's called, a new `currentCallbackId` and bound function are created.

Comment: cope.$watch('source' will trigger the callback several times, for each time the value of currentCallbackId will change and bind to the new callback

Answer (score 0):

I find a simplest solution :

```
scope.$watch('source.$$state.value', function (data) {
    if( !data ) return ;
    dataToView( data );
});
```

that make sure I not register to anyting but get the fresh Data when it done on the current source

Comment: Where is `d` coming from? It's throwing an error when I execute it in my head :)